# Un-round fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, arithmetic, rational-numbers

When you convert a fraction to a decimal number and you want to store that number, you often have to round it, because you only want to use a certain amount of memory. Let's say you can only store 5 decimal digits, then  5/3 becomes 1.6667. If you can store only 2 decimal digits it will be 1.7 (now assuming that it is always between 0 and 9.99...).

If you now try to reverse that process with 1.7 and you want to get your fraction back, that can be difficult, since you know that 1.7 is only a rounded number. Of course you can try 17/10 but that is rather an 'ugly' fraction compared to the 'elegant' 5/3.

So the goal is now finding the fraction a/b with the least denominator b, that results in the rounded decimal number when correctly rounded.

### Details

The input contains a string with a number of 1 up to 5 digits that is between 0 (including) and 10 (not including) with a '.' after the first digit. Let's say `n` denotes the number of digits. The output must be a list/array of two integers `[numerator, denominator]` or a rational datatype (you can create your own or use built-in) where the numerator is non-negative and the denominator is positive.  The fraction numerator/denominator must be equal to the input when correctly rounded to `n` digits (which means `n-1` digits after the decimal point).

**Restriction: only one loop statement allowed.** This means that you can use only one single looping statement (like `for` or `while` or `goto` etc. as well as functional loops like `map` or `fold` that apply code to every element of a list/array) in your whole code, but you are free to 'abuse' it or use recursion etc.

You should write a function. If your language does not have functions (or even if it does), you can alternatively assume that the input is stored in a variable (or input via stdin) and print the result or write it to a file. The lowest number of bytes wins.

#### Rounding

The rounding should follow the 'conventional' rounding rules, i.e. if the last digit that will be cut off is 5 or greater, you will round up, and you will round down for any other cases, so e.g:

4.5494 will result when rounding to

- 1 digit:  5
- 2 digits: 4.5
- 3 digits: 4.55
- 4 digits: 4.549

### Examples

Please include following test cases and other 'interesting' ones:

```
Input 1.7     Output 5/3
Input 0.      Output 0/1
Input 0.001   Output 1/667
Input 3.1416  Output 355/113
```

Comment: Thank you for these thougths: Since I am not used to both I ask you: What would you recommend? I think I have to allow functions like `map` etc but I'd disallow the output of a rational type. @ rounding: I will specify this, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I think that should make sense now. Do you think that is an acceptable 'definition' I wrote down of functions like `map`?

Comment: Yes, sounds good. Alternatively "... that apply a named or anonymous function repeatedly." E.g. Mathematica has `Nest`, which isn't applied to a list, but still creates a loop.

Comment: But in functional languages there is no such a thing as a loop. Foe example in haskell `repeat` creates an infinite list of its argument. I t seems to loop but it actually has time complexity of O(1). But i guess sorting each case individually is better than not allowing functional languages.

Comment: I don't like the current definition of "loop".  In Python, for example, `for n in numbers: f(g(n))` is equivalent to `map(f, map(g, numbers))`.  The functional version uses `map` twice, should that really be disallowed?

Comment: maybe have a bonus for no loops at all?

Comment: @proudhaskeller As I read it, functional loops aren't disallowed, but are allowed exactly once like any other loop.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I talked about the case that functional languages would be disallowed because of ambiguity

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot really contribute to that discussion since my knowledge about functional programming is basically zero. If you have a solution of which you are unsure about whether it complies with the 'rules' please submit it anyway! In the end it is supposed to be a fun and educational challenge!

Comment: I'm curious: Why does it *have* to be a function? Why can't we submit programs?

Comment: @Dennis No that was unfortunate wording, you can submit it in any form you like, the main idea behind that paragraph was that you should not have a disadvantage if your language takes more bytes for 'reading' the input number.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I even thought about that in the first place but was too lazy to figure out a way of making that bonus happen. I suggest that you can pat yourself on your shoulder twice if you make it without any loops? =)

Comment: @flawr I did infact

Comment: Do implicit loops count? In array languages like J or APL, each verb introduces an implicit loop. If implicit loops counted, this would be impossible to do in APL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CJam, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
Q'./1=,:L0\{;)_Qd*mo_d2$/LmOQd-}g'/@
```

Asuumes the input string is stored in Q, which is explicitly allowed by the question. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net)

#### Test cases

```
$ for d in 1.7 0. 0.001 3.1416; do cjam <(echo "\"$d\":Q;
> Q'./1=,:L0\{;)_Qd*mo_d2$/LmOQd-}g'/@
> "); echo; done
5/3
0/1
1/667
355/113
```

#### How it works

```
Q'./1=,:L  " Count the number of characters after the dot and store it in L.     ";
0\         " Push 0 (denominator) and swap it with L (dummy value).              ";
{          "                                                                     ";
  ;        " Discard the topmost item from the stack (numerator or dummy value). ";
  )        " Increment the denominator.                                          ";
  _Qd*mo   " Multiply a copy by Double(Q) and round.                             ";
  _d2$/    " Cast a copy to Double and it divide it by the denominator.          ";
  LmO      " Round to L digits.                                                  ";
  Qd       " If the result is not Double(Q),                                     ";
}g         " repeat the loop.                                                    ";
./@        " Push a slash and rotate the denominator on top of it.               ";
```

Answer (score 15):

### T-SQL 254

While T-SQL isn't really suited to this sort of thing, it wa fun to try. The performance gets real bad the higher the denominator.  It is limited to a denominator of 1000.

Input is a float variable @

```
WITH e AS(SELECT *FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0))n(n)),t AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT \))N FROM e a,e b,e c,e d)SELECT TOP 1concat(n.n,'/',d.n)FROM t d,t n WHERE round(n.n/(d.n+.0),len(parsename(@,1)))=@ ORDER BY d.n,n.n
```

A breakdown of the query

```
WITH                                      -- Start CTE(Common Table Expression)
 e AS(                                    --Create a set of 10 rows
   SELECT *
   FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0))n(n)
 ),
 t AS(                                    
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT \))N 
   FROM e a,e b,e c,e d                   --Cross join e to produce 1000 numbered rows
 )
SELECT 
  TOP 1                                   --Grab first result
  concat(n.n,'/',d.n)                     --Build output
FROM t d,t n                              --Cross join t against itself for denominator and numerator
WHERE round(
  n.n/(d.n+.0),                           --Force float division with +.0
  len(parsename(@,1))                     --Get rounding length
  )=@                                     --Filter where the rounded result = input
ORDER BY d.n,n.n                          --Order by denominator then numerator
```

Comment: +1. I love it. I put in `3.14159` and it duly gave me `355/113`

Comment: +1 I never expected to see an SQL language here!!!

Comment: @TomChantler I suspect you mean eventually :)

Comment: @flawr To be honest I didn't think it was going to work .. very brute force method though.

Answer (score 12):

## Haskell, <s>62</s> 59

if only the names weren't so long...

```
import Data.Ratio
f s=approxRational(read s)$50/10^length s
```

this is a function returning a `Rational` value.

**explanation:**
the function `approxRational` is a function which takes a float number and a float epsilon and returns the most simple rational which is in distance epsilon of the input. basically, returns the most simple approximation of the float to a rational in a "forgivable error" distance.

let's exploit this function for our use. for this we will need to figure out what is the area of the floats that round up to the given number. then getting this into the `approxRational` function will get us the answer.

let's try 1.7, for example. the lowest float that rounds to 1.7 is 1.65. any lower will not round to 1.7. similarly, the upper bound of the floats that round to 1.7 is 1.75.
both limits are the bounds are the input number +/- 0.05. it can be easily shown that this distance is always `5 * 10 ^ -(the length of the input - 1)` (the -1 is because there is always a '.' in the input). from here the code is quite simple.

**test cases:**

```
*Main> map f ["1.7", "0.001", "3.1416"]
[5 % 3,1 % 667,355 % 113]
```

unfortunately it doesn't work on "0." because Haskell's parser function doesn't recognize a `.` at the end of a float. this can be fixed for 5 bytes by replacing `read s` by `read$s++"0"`.

Comment: It's an interesting function to have. Ordinarily such functions exist for the purpose of finding the best rational approximation to a number in the fewest steps, which is provably accomplished using truncated continued fraction representations. Alternatively, finding a fraction with the lowest denominator is more an academic curiosity. One ordinarily wouldn't expect to find it as a standard library function.

Comment: @COTO Well, this is Haskell, it is full of academic research.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>127</s> 125 bytes

```
f=->n{b=q=r=(m=n.sub(?.,'').to_r)/d=10**p=n.count('0-9')-1
b=r if(r=(q*d-=1).round.to_r/d).round(p).to_f.to_s==n while d>1
b}
```

Defines a function `f` which returns the result as a `Rational`. E.g. if you append this code

```
p f["1.7"]
p f["0."]
p f["0.001"]
p f["3.1416"]
```

You get

```
(5/3)
(0/1)
(1/667)
(355/113)
```

The loop is over denominators. I'm starting with the full fraction, e.g. `31416/10000` for the last example. Then I'm decrementing the denominator, proportionally decrement the numerator (and round it). If the resulting rational rounds to the same as the input number, I'm remembering a new best fraction.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.7+, 111 characters

Proof that you can write horrible code in any language:

```
def f(s):
 t,e,y=float(s),50*10**-len(s),1;n=d=x=0
 while x|y:n,d=n+x,d+y;a=1.*n/d;x,y=a<t-e,a>t+e
 return n,d
```

### Output

```
>>> [f(s) for s in ("1.7", "0.", "0.001", "3.1416")]
[(5, 3), (0, 1), (1, 667), (355, 113)]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <strike>49</strike> 53 characters

```
Rationalize[ToExpression@#,5 10^(1-StringLength@#)]&@
```

Usage:

```
Rationalize[ToExpression@#,5 10^(1-StringLength@#)]&@"1.7"
```

Output:

```
5/3
```

Test cases:

```
input: 1.7     output: 5/3
input: 0.      output: 0
input: 0.001   output: 1/999
input: 3.1416  output: 355/113
```

The 0.001 case strikes me as odd; as the rationalize function didn't work according to its description, when it didn't find the 1/667 case.
It should output the number with the smallest denominator that is within specified bounds.

Comment: haha I used the exact same solution. too bad in Haskell it's longer. btw, it doesn't look like your solution takes a string as an input as is required by spec.

Comment: Wait, the input was a string?
Dang, that means I can pull some stuff out of the code.

Comment: Your output for `0.001` doesn't match the OP because `Rationalize` isn't under the constraint to minimize the denominator. As I mentioned to proud haskeller, a rational approximation function subject to minimizing the denominator is highly esoteric (in short because it's a lousy and inefficient way to approximate numbers). I ordinarily wouldn't expect it to be a standard library function.

Comment: @COTO According to the docs it *does* minimise the denominator though.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: It is kind of interesting that it outputs `1/999`. 999 becomes the (acceptable) lowest denominator only for an error between roughly 1e-6 and 2e-6. The error bound is clearly 5e-4. So whatever Mathematica is doing in that case, it definitely isn't working to spec. :P

Comment: @COTO I guess this would be a useful function if you calculated some floating point math and wanted to get the result as a rational. If we calculated, lets say, 2/3, then although 6666667/1000000 or whatever is closer to the float in memory but 2/3 is much more likely to be the true result

Comment: @COTO i mean if we wanted to get a 100% correct rational from a math expression which is a rational

Comment: This is just a guess, but perhaps the error is due to the decimal point being included in the string length?

Comment: @Martin You are correct, I forgot that the first part needed to be converted from a string as well... Changing stuff again...

Comment: @proudhaskeller: I agree with you on why the spec selects the lowest denominator, and Mathematica is the kind of academically-oriented language that I'd expect to have such a function. For most languages, the only things that would matter are 1) whether the rational approximation meets the error spec, and 2) speed. And finding the rational with the lowest denominator is most definitely not a fast approach. There are other approaches that will find fractions with "reasonably" low denominators in a tiny fraction of the time.

Comment: @COTO well, the implementation of `approxRational` doesn't Just check every Rational, it has a specific algorithm. I haven't worked out how it works though. so I don't really know what is the time Complexity, but it seems to be efficient.

Comment: @COTO it seems to have some similarities to the gcd algorithm

Answer (score 3):

### APL, 50

```
2↑⍎⍕(⍎x←⍞){50>|(10*⍴x)×⍺-⍵÷⍨n←⌊.5+⍺×⍵:n ⍵⋄''}¨⍳1e5
```

As long as you don't count `eval` and `toString` as loops

**Explanation**

The approach is to iterate over 1 to 10000 as denominator and calculate the numerator that most closely match the float, then check if the error is within bounds. Lastly, select the smallest pair from all the fractions found.

`(⍎x←⍞)` Take string input from screen, assign to `x`, and eval
`⍳1e5` Generate array from 1 to 10000
`{...}¨` For each element of the array, call function with it and `(⍎x←⍞)` and arguments **(loop)**

`⍺×⍵` Multiply the arguments
`⌊.5+` Round off (by adding 0.5 then rounding down)
`n←` Assign to `n`
`⍺-⍵÷⍨` Divide by right argument, then subtract from left argument
`(10*⍴x)×` Multiply by 10 to the power of "length of `x`"
`|` Take absolute value
`50>` Check if less than 50 (length of `x` is 2 more than the no. of d.p., so use 50 here instead of 0.5)
`:n ⍵⋄''` If the previous check returns true, then return the array of `n` and the right argument, else return empty string.

`⍎⍕` `toString` and then `eval` to get an array of all the numbers in the array
`2↑` Select only the first 2 elements, which is the first numerator-denominator pair found

Answer (score 2):

## BC, <s>151</s> 148 bytes

## Edit - faster and shorter version

```
define f(v){s=scale(x=v);for(i=r=1;i<=10^s;i+=1){t=v*i+1/2;scale=0;p=t/=1;scale=s+1;t=t/i+10^-s/2;scale=s;t=t/1-v;if((t*=-1^(t<0))<r){r=t;n=p;d=i}}}
```

same test case.

A lot is similar to the previous version, but instead of trying all possible n / d combinations, we hill-climb over the residues of v and backward quotients of multiples m==v*d and denominators d. Again the precision of the computation is the same.

Here is it untangled:

```
define f(v)
{
    s= scale(x=v)
    for( i=r=1; i <= 10^s; i+=1 ){
        t= v * i +1/2
        scale=0
        m=t/=1 # this rounded multiple becomes nominator if
               # backward quotient is first closest to an integer
        scale=s+1
        t= t / i +10^-s/2 # divide multiple back by denominator, start rounding again...
        scale=s
        t= t/1 - v # ...rounding done. Signed residue of backward quotient
        if( (t*= -1^(t < 0)) < r ){
            r=t
            n=m
            d=i
        }
    }
}
```

This version really has a mere single loop and does only $\Theta\left(\operatorname{fractional_decimals}(v)\right)$ arithmetic operations.

## Original - slow version

This functions computes the smallest nominator n and denominator d such that the fraction n / d rounded to fractional_decimals(v) digits is equal to a given decimal value v.

```
define f(v){s=scale(v);j=0;for(i=r=1;j<=v*10^s;){scale=s+1;t=j/i+10^-s/2;scale=s;t=t/1-v;if((t*=-1^(t<0))<r){r=t;n=j;d=i};if((i+=1)>10^s){i=1;j+=1}};v}
```

test case:

```
define o(){ print "Input ",x,"\tOutput ",n,"/",d,"\n" }
f(1.7); o()
> 0
> Input 1.7       Output 5/3
> 0
f(0.); o()
> 0
> Input 0 Output 0/1
> 0
f(0.001); o()
> 0
> Input .001      Output 1/667
> 0
f(3.1416); o()
> 0
> Input 3.1416    Output 355/113
> 0
```

And here is it untangled:

```
define f(v)
{
    s=scale(x=v) # save in global for later print
    j=0
    # do a full sequential hill-climb over the residues r of v and all possible
    # fractions n / d with fractional_decimals(v) == s precision.
    for( i=r=1; j <= v * 10^s; ){
        scale=s+1
        t= j / i +10^-s/2 # start rounding...
        scale=s
        t= t/1 - v # ...rounding done. New residue, but still signed
        if( (t*= -1^(t < 0)) < r ){ # absolute residue better?
            # climb hill
            r=t
            n=j
            d=i
        }
        if( (i+=1) > 10^s ){ # next inner step. End?
            # next outer step
            i=1
            j+=1
        }
    }
    v
}
```

I admit, I cheated a little by emulating a second inner loop inside a single outer loop, but without using any further loop statements. And that's why it actually does $\Theta\left(v \operatorname{fractional_decimals}(v)^2\right)$ arithmetic operations.

Comment: you should probably move the new version to the front of the post

Comment: @proudhaskeller done

Answer (score 2):

## GNU dc, 72 bytes

No loops - dc doesn't even have them.  Instead the control comes from a single tail-recursive macro - idiomatic for dc.

```
?dXAr^d2*sf*sq1sd0[ld1+sd]sD[r1+r]sN[dlf*ld/1+2/dlq>Ndlq<Dlq!=m]dsmxpldp
```

### Output:

```
$ for n in 1.7 0. 0.001 3.1416; do echo "    n = $n:"; dc unround.dc <<< $n; done
    n = 1.7:
5
3
    n = 0.:
0
1
    n = 0.001:
1
667
    n = 3.1416:
355
113
$
```

Phew.  Partial explanation in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38152/11259).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 111 characters

```
f=Module[{a=0,b=1,k},While[Round[a/b,10^-(StringLength[#]-2)]!=(k=ToExpression)@#,If[N[a/b]>k@#,b++,a++]];a/b]&
```

Pretty simple really, and I don't think it converges anywhere as fast as the other solutions, since the numerator and denominator only increment by one. I mostly wanted to find the simple solution to this. I'll have to see the other answers and see what clever stuff happens there.

### Output

```
f/@{"1.7","0.0","0.001","3.1416","3.14"}
{5/3, 0, 1/667, 355/113, 22/7}
```

Does anyone here celebrate [Pi Approximation Day](http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=955)?

Comment: No, I am only celebrating tau approximation day.=P But i just noticed that |355/113 - pi|<10^-6 =)

Answer (score 2):

## Applescript, >300 bytes

I wanted to do this in a language that natively does the type of rounding required.  Turns out Applescript fits the bill.  Then I saw the enum [`rounding as taught in school`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW43), and couldn't resist the using it, despite the blatant uncompetitiveness of Applescript for golfing purposes:

```
on u(q)
    set n to 0
    set d to 1
    set x to 0
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set f to 10 ^ (q's text item 2's length)
    repeat until x = q as real
        set x to (round n * f / d rounding as taught in school) / f
        if x < q then set n to n + 1
        if x > q then set d to d + 1
    end repeat
    return {n, d}
end u

log my u("1.7")
log my u("0.")
log my u("0.001")
log my u("3.1416")
```

This can be golfed a bit more, but probably not worth it.

#### Output:

```
(*5, 3*)
(*0, 1*)
(*1, 667*)
(*355, 113*)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 233

This works by calling a rationalization function r() with a starting denominator of 1. The function begins incrementing a numerator, and checking at every increment whether the resulting number, when rounded to the same number of digits as the original, has the same string representation as the original. Once the numerator has been incremented so much that the result is greater than the original, the function increments the denominator and calls itself.

This of course uses much more code, but I think the spirit of the problem exonerates this bare-bones approach; for all we know, the internal rationalize() functions of modern languages have lots of internal loops.

Note that this doesn't work for an input of "0." because that is not a standard way to write a float, so when it re-writes the float to string, the result will never be a "0.".

The specs want a function that returns values instead of just printing to screen, hence the argument-passing.

Code (ungolfed):

```
void r(char* x, int* a, int* b) {
    int i = -1;
    char z[32];
    double v =atof(x);
    while(1) {
        i++;
        double y = ((double)i)/((double)(*b));
        double w;
        sprintf(z, "%.*f", strlen(strchr(x,'.'))-1, y);
        if(strcmp(x, z)==0) {
            *a = i;
            return;
        }
        w = atof(z);
        if(w > v) {
            (*b)++;
            r(x, a, b);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int num;
    int denom = 1; // start with a denominator of 1
    r(argv[1], &num, &denom);
    printf("%d/%d\n", num, denom);
    return 0;
}
```

Golfed code:

```
typedef double D;
void r(char*x,int*a,int*b){int i=-1;char z[32];D v=atof(x);while(1){i++;D y=((D)i)/((D)(*b));D w;sprintf(z,"%.*f",strlen(strchr(x,'.'))-1,y);if(!strcmp(x,z)){*a=i;return;}w=atof(z);if(w>v){(*b)++;r(x,a,b);return;}}}
```

Comment: actually, in the Haskell library implementation (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Ratio.html#approxRational), the definition of `approxRational` has Just one recursive helper function, and no more looping than that.

Comment: well, I was wrong, it actually has two recursive helper functions, but by the spec it is okay

Comment: I wasn't trying to say that anyone's solutions were invalid, just wanted to post one without built-in rationalization :)

Comment: of course, but the fact that the definition itself has no loops is nice, and infact, you wrote in your post "for all we know, the internal rationalize() functions of modern languages have lots of internal loops." so I checked it.

Comment: anyway, how does the solution work?

Comment: Added a section that explains how it works.

Comment: @flawr i'm not sure that having the function expect a `1` is legal. is it?

Comment: @proudhaskeller Sorry, I cannot follow what you mean? In what way does his function expect what? (Or has his post changed in meantime?)

Comment: @flawr if you will read carefully you will notice that in order for the function to work the third parameter must be initialized to 1

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Bash, 92 bytes

As a partial explanation for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38148/11259), here it is ported to bash:

```
f=${1#*.}
q=${1//.}
for((n=0,d=1;x-q;x=2*10**${#f}*n/d+1>>1,n+=x<q,d+=x>q));{ :;}
echo $n/$d
```

Notably:

- bash has integer-only arithmetic.  So we appropriately scale everything up by 2*10^(number of fractional digits).
- bash rounds *down* to nearest integer; the 2 in the expression above is so we can instead round to nearest integer (*up or down*).
- Just one loop
- we check if the rational overshoots or undershoots the decimal and increment the denominator or numerator accordingly.

#### Output:

```
$ for n in 1.7 0. 0.001 3.1416; do echo "    n = $n:"; ./unround.sh $n; done
    n = 1.7:
5/3
    n = 0.:
0/1
    n = 0.001:
1/667
    n = 3.1416:
355/113
$
```

Comment: Should be a fairly straightforward `int`-only port to c

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (E6) 85

```javascript
F=r=>(l=>{for(n=r,d=1;l&&r!=((n=r*d+1/2|0)/d).toFixed(l);d++);})(r.length-2)||[n|0,d]
```

**Ungolfed**

```javascript
F=r=>{
  l = r.length-2; // decimal digits
  if (l==0) return [r|0, 1] // if no decimal return the same (conv to number) with denominator 1

  // loop for increasing denominator 
  for(d = 2; 
      r != ( // loop until find an equal result
      // given R=N/D ==> N=R*D
      (n=r*d+1/2|0) // find possible numerator, rounding (+0.5 and trunc)
      /d).toFixed(l); // calc result to given decimals
      d++);
  return [n,d]
}
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```javascript
;["1.7","0.","0.001","3.1416","9.9999"].forEach(v => console.log(v,F(v)))
```

*Output*

```javascript
1.7 [5, 3]
0. [0, 1]
0.001 [1, 667]
3.1416 [355, 113]
9.9999 [66669, 6667]
```