# 80% of respondents agreed…

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Sometimes I see a claim like "80% of respondents agreed" and I think "what was your sample size? 5?" because, of course, with a sample size of 5 it's possible to get 80% to agree on something. If the claim is "47% of respondents agreed" then I know it must be a larger sample size.<sup>[1]</sup>

### challenge

Given a positive integer x≤100, output the minimum number of respondents needed for an honest claim that "x% of respondents agreed".

Input and output will be however integers (or numbers) are normally handled.

This is code golf.

Caveat: Note the effect of [rounding](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer). For example, a claim of "12% of respondents agreed" can mean that there were 8 respondents, 1 agreed, and the claim is rounding half down. Likewise, "13% of respondents agreed" can mean there were 8 respondents, 1 agreed, and the claim is rounding half up. Assume numbers *closest* to an integer are rounded to that integer, but you must account for both of ways of rounding *half*. Thus, on an input of 12 *or* of 13, your algorithm should output 8.

### examples

- 1 ↦ 67
- 2 ↦ 40
- 100 ↦ 1

---

<sup>[1] Of course, this is assuming that what I'm reading is telling the truth.</sup>

Comment: How is the minimum number of respondents calculated?

Comment: I think this is [A239525](https://oeis.org/A239525) without the first term.

Comment: Do standard floating-point error tolerance apply? For instance with python's Fraction module I get `abs(Fraction(13,100).limit_denominator(8) - 13/100) = 
0.0050000000000000044` which rejects 8 as a valid sample size for 13% because the difference is above a half-percent.

Comment: @Stef as noted in the question post, on an input of 13, the output should be 8.

Comment: Related: [Convert a decimal to a fraction, approximately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221196)

Comment: @msh210 [I understand, but the consensus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210572/diophantine-approximation-find-lowest-possible-denominator-to-approximate-withi#comment496246_210572)

Comment: Also related, if not a dupe: [Un-round fractions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38104/24877)

Answer (score 9):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 27 bytes

```
**&~`i$(199*%/:/&=69)-1.99*
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LSUqtLyFTRMLS01FLVt9JXszWz1NQ11ANyubjS1A21FQ0NDACu6ggK)

Based on the formula from the [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A239525):

> Find the smallest N such that there is some x > 0 with abs(100*x/N - n) <= 0.5.

For golfing reasons this actually checks -1 < 1.99*(100*x/N - n) < 1, which happens to be equivalent on the domain of the problem.

Comment: Why the 1.99 instead of 2 (or 2.0)?

Comment: @justhalf Because I need the strict comparison. K has no absolute value function, so what I'm doing for this check is `round_to_zero(1.99*(100*x/N - n)) == 0`

Comment: Ah, so it's actually checking -1 <= 1.99*(100*x/N - n) <= 1 in the code? The explanation in the last paragraph seems to already include the strict comparison, so I was confused.

Comment: No, it is strict. With `2*` you would need `<=` comparison. For example with `n=12`: `1.99*(100*1/8 - 12)=0.995<1, 2*(100*1/8 - 12)=1<=1`

Comment: Ah, ok, because `round_to_zero` checks for <1, got it. It would still work if the code were -1 <= 1.99*(100*x/N - n) <= 1, right (that's what I meant in previous comment).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 thanks to Nick Kennedy! (Make a 100 by 100 table with values over 100% rather than a triangle of values.)

```
ạȷ2÷þ×¤ḤỊ§TḢ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer from \$[1,100]\$, the reported percentage, and yields another positive integer, the minimal number of respondents.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4bqhyLcyw7fDvsOXwqThuKThu4rCp1ThuKL///80)** Or see [all 100](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroUnthsd3n543@Hph5Y83LHk4e6uQ8tDHu5Y9B8k3v6oac1/AA).

#### How?

```
ạȷ2÷þ×¤ḤỊ§TḢ - Link: positive intger from [1..100], P
      ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 ȷ2          -   10^2 -> 100
    þ        -   {[1..100]} x {[1..100]} table of:
   ÷         -     divide
     ×       -   multiply by {100} (vectorises)
                 -> [[100],[50.0,100],[33.33,66.66,100],[25.0,50.0,75.0,100],...]
ạ            - {P} absolute difference (vectorises) {that}
       Ḥ     - double (vectorises)
        Ị    - is insignificant? (vectorises) - i.e. abs(x)<=1
         §   - sums
          T  - truthy indices
           Ḣ - head
```

Comment: [`ạȷ2÷þ×¤ḤỊ§TḢ`](https://tio.run/#%23y0rNyan8/3DXwhPbjYIOb1d51LTm8PRDSx7uWPJwd9eh5SEPdyyCyh7efngfhpShgcHhdqAe28MTgeR/AA) saves two at the expense of lower efficiency (generates 10000 percentages rather than 5050).

Comment: Good call, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>g=i=>(x-i%69/(y=i>>7)*100)**2<.26?y:g(-~i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRDkNAEAXQr2kys6ziQVPM@hbBbm4jRpCGl/761nk9n/7b78OG9bCLjlP0Ek9xQSCOTotH9X7SJXDuxabIczambLOy6q46kP2Bo9eNIEWDVu5vkgQ86LLrPGWzBkLqCUzM8Q8)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
i;j;f(n){for(i=j=1;fabs(100.*j/i-n)>.5;j=--j?:++i);j=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBdb4IwFH33V9yQmLRKlfrB5jrcw7JfMX1gtXVlWg0lGZnhr49doOgkPW0595yT3ivZXsq6NiITmlh60aecmCRLuNDphyM8iiajbGqYpevJUmQJY9nL03hsKN6NqGpjCzimxhIKlwHg1xCqPCtZqN37FhK4xA8hLKIQZivEPASOJ48RC8QMwRFYR/qxXajnXhf7Mp7LzrHyxSbUZzUCb4t6ayXa18iTdQXIzzQf4a7kl8q7RwWb8m22KVeviGUQwv//eeDdOAwgTUPG7lSJtkj46zM486NOmvSt0qknRldGAM6pUdM2rBtPP6IC07qoMXBxV3JY0qSg96xC9jrX1rm9Cc45SjQJhjtga8B96DYWuypCcOG1cZckautjq0FV/0p9SPeuZt81Oxz/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 14 bytes

```
₅Dᵒ÷×ṚTȧd1≤ᶤaꜝ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLigoVE4bWSw7fDl+G5mlTIp2Qx4omk4bakYeqcnSIsIiIsIjQiLCIzLjIuMCJd)

Takes an integer argument and returns an integer argument. This is a Vyxal 3 translation of @JonathanAllan’s Jelly answer. It’s two bytes longer, partly because the outer modifier returns the result in the transposed reverse of what is needed for this problem.

```
₅Dᵒ÷×ṚTȧd1≤ᶤaꜝ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
₅               # ‎⁡100
 D              # ‎⁢Triplicate
  ᵒ÷            # ‎⁣Outer divide by using (100..1),(100..1)
    ×           # ‎⁤Multiply (by 100)
     Ṛ          # ‎⁢⁡Reverse
      T         # ‎⁢⁢Transpose
       ȧ        # ‎⁢⁣Absolute difference with main input
        d       # ‎⁢⁤Double
         1≤     # ‎⁣⁡Less than or equal to 1
           ᶤa   # ‎⁣⁢Find first where any true
             ꜝ  # ‎⁣⁣Increment by 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 35 bytes

Prompts for input:

```
⌊/(⎕=(⌈n-.5),⌊.5+n←100×÷m)/m,m←⍳100
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6OeLn0NoJitxqOejjxdPVNNHaCQnql2HkiNgcHh6Ye352rq5@rkAvmPejcDhf4DNXL9T@My5ErjMgJiQzBhDCIMDLi4uAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>85</s> 72 bytes

-13 bytes since I saw answers to other questions use a function

```python
lambda x:[a for a in range(68)for b in range(a)if abs(x-100*b/a)<=.5][0]
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEADP5hV7zApqiihS7EtKDxvqaiDZhCSH9vWRePEyMHOYtNdPlGvjSTdPwa4E2zgTcMxA4AQyyful7w/sxf4LoWMgW/R2Gow52gvhczrfltksDRXnGKDsBVxIMVcodXWi@sL3xU9HdUjZSdWsOz0ituEL), or see [all the numbers](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZqvxPycxNyklUaHCKjpRIS2/SCFRITNPoSgxLz1Vw8xCEySShBBJ1MxMU0hMKtao0DU0MNBK0k/UtLHVM42NNoj9r8kVXVCUmVeikaaRo6kJNisHodNQB6hBM/Y/AA)

pre-golf:

```python
x=int(input())
for a in range(68):        # for all denominators (starting from lowest)
 for b in range(a):        # and numerators (bonus, doesn't let /0 through)
  if abs(x-100*b/a)<=.5:   # is it within rounding range, up or down?
   print(a)                # then print the denominator
   exit()                  # anything else will be bigger
```

credit to [oeis](https://oeis.org/A239525) for sequence and formula

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞.ΔтLт*s/α2zs@à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTLjb5XGzSKtY/t9Goqtjh8IL//w2NAQ) or [verify all outputs](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9vc2FiaWX/0YJFTj8iIOKGkiAiP07Cqf/iiJ4uzpTRgkzRgipzL8KuzrEyenNAw6D/fSz/).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞                # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 .Δ              # Pop and find the first/smallest that's truthy for:
   тL            #  Push a list in the range [1,100]
     т*          #  Multiply each by 100: [100,200,...,10000]
       s/        #  Divide each by the current integer
         α       #  Get the absolute difference of each with the (implicit) input
          2zs@   #  Check for each whether it's <= 0.5:
          2      #   Push 2
           z     #   Pop and push 1/2
            s    #   Swap so the list is at the top
             @   #   >= check
              à  #  Pop and check if any in the list is truthy
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
∞.ΔDÝs/т*α2zs@à
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//@KIni7OlETDnXMv0YIqzrEyenNAw6D//zE)

Explanation:

```
∞        Push infinite list
.Δ       Find first item in list where:
    D    Duplicate item
    Ý    Create an array 0-N
    s/   Switch last two and divide
    т*   Multiply by 100
    α    Absolute difference (input is automatically in stack)
    2zs  Push 0.5 before the last item
    @    Compare 0.5 with list (>=)
à        Check if the list contains 1
```

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you for the response! I didn't notice this previously, I believe that this only works when n in the formula used (see other responses) is 1.

Comment: @Arnauld I fixed the bug. I'm now tied with the other 05AB1E answer, but that doesn't work for 0 so I think I still win.

Comment: Note that the question states the input will be a "positive integer ≤ 100", i.e. nonzero

Comment: @noodleman Yes. But based on the challenge explanation, logically it should contain. My solution runs faster and supports 0 as an input so I believe that I won.

Comment: The tiebreaker for code-golf is always which solution was posted earlier. The other solution works correctly according to the challenge’s specification.

Comment: @noodleman I know. My solution is better though.

Comment: @Flummox "Winning" doesn't really mean anything here anymore; we're all here to have a good time, no need to worry about whose solution is "better".

Comment: @Ginger I'm aware

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⌊Φφ∧ιΦφ¬‹·⁵↔⁻θ∕×λ¹⁰⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvLCsIwEEX3fkWWE4iSIq66EkUQtLjwB9I24EAeNjPp749xJZ7lPfdML1em7ILINb0rDzWOvsCi@82jYGI4OWK4Y8JYI1wwcLOdtdaoY5oBjfrbhsxw80SwO7TDSDlU9t@8EixGnXHF2cMToycIRrVIG4X6Ry/S7WW7hg8) Link is to verbose version of code. Very slow as it does about 1,000 times as much work as necessary. Explanation: Uses the OEIS formula.

```
Ｎθ                          First input as a number
     φ                      Predefined variable `1000`
    Φ                       Filter on implicit range
       ι                    Current value
      ∧                     Logical And
         φ                  Predefined variable `1000`
        Φ                   Filter on implicit range
                   λ        Inner value
                  × ¹⁰⁰     Multiplied by `100`
                 ∕          Divided by
                       ι    Outer value
              ↔⁻            Absolute difference with
                θ           Input number
          ¬‹·⁵              Is less than or equal to `0.5`
   ⌊                        Take the minimum
  Ｉ                         Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 53 bytes

```r
f=\(n,x=1)`if`(all(abs(n-100*(1:x)/x)>.5),f(n,x+1),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpbCoAgEACvs1tWWgRR2Fm0YEGQDXqAt9/SfmYYmFOELD283@FgYJWsQRfIgY8R/HYBN0brCsycsEu4tiMqyl9tUCUUggkXgj7jG4v@GApRXg)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 66 bytes

```
{for(;i++<99;)for(j=0;j++<r=i;)if(.5>=(n=$1-100*j/i)&&n>=-.5)next}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJBjhMxEEX3dYpS1BolzGToKttlF6HDBrbcgQUjdYgCao0EUtSnQOw4HRcJ9Q2biVqW26r3/89vf/r@5Xadp3GlK3H85qftsrt@W@bLM5/nB97sj5sHXuKZpvPybvPn98/Nm1h/xel5WTtznqdB/u2WaVBab9enr8v2MN/fv3U/7PBymsbDKd6XaT7swuSxHKftJbi9jOOr0@t5d3d3OU77x7K7fP7xvN4@fHz/P8YgL2MM@jLGoOtN2Cop55ESq1NmTVRYnIzFqLJkaixKziIkI8tIIuwkyo0kYclcSYJJJAZSKhtJ64BDRUcupAIt1WA1YVgzS1gXjtPOaQWiATZSD9HU7ZJgOilGUuLYZiRNBXgyMKlGjtSwOOgMwywYyIr0OYVczuGdC4Bs0MxhGHONNU6cU6EyslKRvlUcl4SRkjFeOlosVEoNvdKLKQ4bg6MJzA3NGJqxDMB6UDOEthr5rfV@HZq1/8UqIVcVdE1gasZIRTfVgNfap1t4V@8fBYZNUG9TIC1F661zrX@MZiHa0ExDM82D9W7nAsB7M56g5hlC3j@8G@6AV@T1hpvhjksS142F/gI)